# Visual C++ express: separate command arguments

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, parameters, command-line-arguments

I'm having weird troubles when trying to pass command arguments to my C program on my Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Everything seems perfect if I write this as the parameters: `a b` . It makes he sees that "a" is the first parameter and "b" is the second (to know it, I'm watching the argv array), using the space character as the delimiter.

But if I try this:

> C:\Desktop\pacoteprincipal\EP2-AED2\"arq1.txt"
>   C:\Desktop\pacoteprincipal\EP2-AED2\"arq2.txt"

, the useful stuff for my program, it sees the whole sentence as being the first argument, and the second argument receives nothing. Note that there is a space character between "arq1.txt" and C:\

Has someone any idea of what is going on? I don't think it's some issue with my program, since the breakpoint is at the first line of the main method.

I am on Windows XP.

Comment: `"C:\Desktop\pacoteprincipal\EP2-AED2\arq1.txt" "C:\D
esktop\pacoteprincipal\EP2-AED2\arq2.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes (`"`) are throwing it off.

```
C:\Desktop\pacoteprincipal\EP2-AED2\"arq1.txt"
                                    ^        ^
C:\Desktop\pacoteprincipal\EP2-AED2\"arq2.txt"
                                    ^        ^
```

If they're necessary, try the following:

```
C:\Desktop\pacoteprincipal\EP2-AED2\\"arq1.txt\"
C:\Desktop\pacoteprincipal\EP2-AED2\\"arq2.txt\"
```

Note the `\` before each `"`. This is called escaping.

If they're not necessary, remove them:

```
C:\Desktop\pacoteprincipal\EP2-AED2\arq1.txt
C:\Desktop\pacoteprincipal\EP2-AED2\arq2.txt
```